# 'Controller as' syntax or services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have several templates in my angular application, I intend to insert them dynamically, some of them might need to share data, maybe even use the same controller.

I've seen lately many examples of the 'ng-controller as' syntax as a way to accomplish this, and most of what i've read, support this approach, but I don't know, I feel suspicious about it.

I want to know what would be the advantages and/or disadvantages of doing something like this (each div is an inserted snippet/template):

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as main">  
  mainController: <input type="text" ng-model="main.someValue" />
  main.someValue: {{ main.someValue }}
  <div ng-controller="anotherController as another">
    anotherController: <input type="text" ng-model="another.someValue" />
    main.someValue: {{ main.someValue }}
  </div>
</div>
```

When I could do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">  
  mainController: <input type="text" ng-model="someValue" />
  someValue: {{ someValue }}
</div> 

<div ng-controller="anotherController">
  anotherController: <input type="text" ng-model="anotherValue" />
  someValue: {{ someValue }}
</div>
```

With a service to connect the data in my two templates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using option one will avoid the dreaded prototypical scope inheritance issue (Google "Angular dot notation") and it is more inline with where the Angular team is going in terms of future features and functionality.

Comment: But wouldn't it be pointless to avoide the dot notation if I have to preside my variable by the namespace of the controller anyways? If I would create a new snippet for example, I would need to know the namespace for each controller and write it accordingly, in opposition to the service option where I would only use the controllers data as it is, and the service would be in charge of managing the connection/binding in the JS side. Also isn't a bit unnatural to have to have embedded snippets just for the purpose of sharing data and not because it makes sense in the DOM?